Conjecture on the increasing efficiency of the shortest minimum-link polygonal chains covering any grids of the form $\{0,1,2\}^k$ as $k$ grows
From the well-known Nine dots problem, we know that we need a polygonal chain with at least $4$ edges to connect the $9$ points of the planar grid $G_{3,2}:=\{\{0, 1, 2\} \times \{0, 1, 2\}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and that, among such polygonal chains, the shortest total Euclidean length achievable is equal to $5 \cdot (1+\sqrt{2}) \approx 12.07106781$ (e.g., a valid solution is the trail $(0,1)-(0,-1)-(3,2)-(0,2)-(2,0)$).
Now, let us move on to the next dimension by assuming that $G_{3,3}:=\{0, 1, 2\}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is given (i.e., a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ regular grid in the well-known Euclidean space).
Accordingly, our goal is to connect all the $27$ points of $G_{3,3}$ by using the minimum-link polygonal chain (i.e., we can only consider the polygonal chains consisting of exactly $13$ edges since in recent years I proved that $\frac{3^k-1}{2}$ edges are optimal for any $k$-dimensional grid $\{0, 1, 2\}^k$ by combining the lower bound arising from Theorem 2.1 of Reference for the lower bound and the constructive upper bound provided by Reference for the upper bound) having the shortest total Euclidean length.
For this purpose, let us denote as $\min(P_{3,3} )$ such minimum length achievable.
Then, it is trivial to point out that $\min(P_{3,3}) > 3^3-1$ while a constructive upper bound is provided by the polygonal chain $$(2,1,1)-(0,3,1)-(0,0,1)-(2,0,1)-(0,2,-1)-(3,2,2)-(-1,2,2)-(2,-1,2)-(2,2,2)-(0,0,2)-(2,2,0)-(2,0,0)-(0,0,0)-(0,2,0)$$ whose total (Euclidean) length is $2 \cdot (9 + 5\cdot \sqrt{2} + 2 \cdot \sqrt{3}) \approx 39.07033885$.
Hence, we have shown that $26 < \min(P_{3,3}) \leq 2 \cdot (9 + 5\cdot \sqrt{2} + 2 \cdot \sqrt{3})$.
Thus, the ratio between the minimum total length of the forests that connect all the points of $G_{3,2}$ and the minimum total length of the polygonal chains with $\frac{3^2-1}{2}$ edges covering the same grid is $\frac{3^2-1}{5 \cdot (1+\sqrt{2})} \approx 0.66274$, and finally we can see that the above-mentioned value is smaller than the corresponding ratio between the minimum total length of the forests connecting the points of $G_{3,3}$ and the minimum total length of the polygonal chains with $\frac{3^3-1}{2}$ edges covering $G_{3,3}$, given the fact that an upper bound for $\min(P_{3,3})$ is $2 \cdot (9 + 5\cdot \sqrt{2} + 2 \cdot \sqrt{3})$ (so that $\frac{3^2-1}{5 \cdot (1+\sqrt{2})} < \frac{3^3-1}{2 \cdot (9 + 5\cdot \sqrt{2} + 2 \cdot \sqrt{3})} \Rightarrow 0.663 < 0.665$ follows).
Question (conjecture): Let $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$ be given and let also $P_{3,k}$ indicate a polygonal chain with (exactly) ${\frac{3^k-1}{2}}$ edges. Is it possible to prove that the inequality $\frac{3^k-1}{\min(P_{3,k})}<\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{\min(P_{3,k+1})}$ holds for every $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$?
